# How can i see if they are of the same type

Tags: java, comparison, dereference

```
private static void ParseInput(String str) 
    {
        char c ;
        Integing item1;
        boolean result;
        int n =str.length();
        Stack StItem = new Stack(n);
        Queue QItem = new Queue(n);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            c = str.charAt(i);
            if ((c == '(') || (c=='[') || (c=='{')){
                Integing item = new Integing(i,c);
                StItem.push(item); 
            }else if((c==')') || (c==']') || (c=='}')){
                item1 = StItem.pop();               
                result = item1.getChar().class ==(c.class); //where i do the check
                if (result ){                     
                    Pair pair1 = new Pair(item1.getNumber(),i);
                    QItem.put(pair1);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Syntax error");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            }
        }           
    }



public class Integing
{
    private int num;
    private char par;

    public  Integing(int numb,char paren)
    {
        num = numb;
        par = paren;
    }

    public  char getChar(){
        return this.par;   //The method i use to get the exact type
    }

    public  int getNumber(){
        return this.num;
    }

}
```

I want to check if item1 and c are of the same type.In fact i have used a method,getChar() to 
    take exactly what i want to check.I found on the internet the method getClass or class.When i 
    use the getClass i have dereference error  and when i use the class i have these errors.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kQZg.png

Comment: Please paste your errors as text, not image. Anyway, c and item1.par are both chars, so how could they be of different types ?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html). You can't call getClass on chars, as char is a primitive type. Again, here it's useless anyway.

Comment: My assignment says that item1.par is a left parentheses since its extracted  from the StItem,so i should check if its the same type as c.Thanks for the link btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for is instanceof, formatted like so:

```
Boolean isChar = item instanceof Character;
```

Here's some documentation on usage: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm

I'm a little confused by what exactly you're trying to do, though - while instanceof fulfills the function you were going for with .class, I can't see how it helps you within the context of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the link,the comparison is really not needed in my code after all.Although,your advice may help others with the comparison of char as it is a primitive class and the .getClass doesnt work! :)